# How do you solve a normal distribution for an expected value?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am working on a problem and am a bit stuck. It is:

For X ~ $\mathcal N $(-2,2) find E(X$^3$)

What I know so far is that:

For X ~ N(0,1) EX = 0 and VarX = 1

I am confused though how we find expected values from that normal distribution. Should I use integrals to solve for this? If so, how do you set up the proper integral (do I use the gaussian equation for this?) I am guessing the integral would go from negative infinity to infinity.

**Edit:** this is the work I have done so far:

For X ~ $\mathcal N $(-2,2) Find E($\ X^3 $)

Z ~ $ \mathcal N $(0, 1)

X = $ \mu $ + $\sigma $X ~ $ \mathcal N $($\mu$,$\sigma^2$)

$\mu$ = -2, $\sigma^2$ = 2, $\sigma$ = $\sqrt 2$

X = -2 + $\sqrt 2$Z w/ Z ~ (0,1)

(X)$^3$ = ($\sqrt 2$Z - 2)$^3$

-12Z$^2$ + 8 (because of symmetry)

Z$^2$ = 1 so therefore E(X$^3$) = -12 + 8 = -4

Does this look correct? How would you set this up simply by definition?

Comment: Why do think $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ although it is given that $X\sim \mathcal N(-2,2)$? If $X\sim \mathcal N(-2,2)$ the expected value is $-2$ and the variance is $2$

Comment: I provided X ~ N(0, 1) as an example, I understand that the same concept can be applied to N(-2,2) but from the expected value and variance how do you derive the E(x^2) or E(X^3)?

Comment: Do you know, or are you allowed to use, moment generating functions? And indeed you can always compute an expectation by definition, $E(X^3)=\int x^3 f(x)\mathrm{dx}$. For a normal RV, yes the bounds of integration are the entire real line.

Comment: I am sure we would be allowed to use them, although I am not very familiar with how to set it up that way. What would that look like? Also, which text editor do you use? I could edit my question to show what I've done so far.

Comment: @Ethan include my @ LoveTooNap29 in future comments in order to notify me with a ping or else I’ll only see comments when I check back in to look. If you are not familiar with MGFs then they are probably not what whoever assigned the problem had in mind for you to use. But it goes, if $M(t):=E(e^{tX})$ is the MGF of $X$ then $E(X^k)=M^{(k)}(0)$ where the superscript is the $k$-th derivative with respect to $t$. Here is a math jax tutorial for typesetting math on the site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Thank you. I have updated my question. Does the way I solved it look like it works? Also, how would I set this up as an integral by definition if I wanted to solve it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea to reduce it to calculating moments of $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ rather than using MGFs or the definition of expectation:

If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, as you know, so that 
$$X^3=\mu^3+3\mu^2 \sigma Z +3 \mu (\sigma Z)^2 +3(\sigma Z)^3,$$
so that upon taking the expectation, we get
$$\mathbb{E}(X^3)=\mu^3+3\mu^2 \sigma \mathbb{E}(Z)+3\mu\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(Z^2)+3 \sigma^3 \mathbb{E}(Z^3).$$
Now after simplifying with the facts that $\mathbb{E}(Z)=0$, $\mathbb{E}(Z^2)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z^3)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^3 \phi(z)\mathrm{dz}=0$ since $\phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$ is an even function and $z^3$ is an odd function so $z^3\phi$ is an odd function and integrating an odd function over a symmetric interval is zero, we finally obtain $E(X^3)=\mu^3+3\mu\sigma^2.$

You can check this is correct by one of the other methods, e.g. if you know $M_X(t):=\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})=e^{\mu t+0.5 \sigma^2 t^2}$ then you can compute three derivatives and verify that $M_X^{'''}(0)=\mathbb{E}(X^3)$.

Note: all odd moments of a standard normal RV are zero by the same argument involving odd/even functions and symmetry.

Hope this helps, comment for clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Looks like I accidentally flipped the sign on the 8.